# form_params method get guzzle php

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I have an API get list user. postmen
[image]

and Headers Content-Type = application/json
- In laravel, I use guzzle to call api
code demo:
$client = new Client();

```
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
    $body = [
        'json' => [
            "filter" => "{}",
            "skip" => 0,
            "limit" => 20,
            "sort" => "{\"createAt\": 1}",
            "select" => "fullname username",
            "populate" => "'right', 'group'",
        ]
    ];
    \Debugbar::info($body);
    $response = $client->get('http://sa-vn.com:2020/api/users/user', [
        'form_params' => $body
    ]);
    echo $response->getBody();
```

But it does not working! please help me

Comment: try to change `[
        'form_params' => $body
    ]` to `$body ` in your request. Also are you getting any error in response

Comment: Thanks Sehdev, But it does not working! "status":"error","data":null,"message":"error: ObjectParameterError: Parameter \"filter\" to find() must be an object, got {}"

Answer (score 1):

form_params and body both are different params in guzzle. check [json](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json)

```
$json = [
    "filter" => json_encode((object)[]),
    "skip" => 0,
    "limit" => 20,
    "sort" => json_encode((object)['createAt'=>1]),
    "select" => "fullname username",
    "populate" => "'right', 'group'"
];

$response = $client->request('get', 'http://sa-vn.com:2020/api/users/user', [
                                                'json' => $json,
                                            ]);
```

If any error occur try without json_encode as well.

```
$json = [
        "filter" => (object)[],
        "skip" => 0,
        "limit" => 20,
        "sort" => (object)['createAt'=>1],
        "select" => "fullname username",
        "populate" => "'right', 'group'"
    ];
```

Comment: select the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

As per Guzzle doucmentation

`form_params`

> Used to send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request.

`json`

> The json option is used to easily upload JSON encoded data as the body of a request. A Content-Type header of application/json will be added if no Content-Type header is already present on the message.

You are passing `json` data in postman. So you can use `json` instead of `form_params`

**Change**

```
$response = $client->get('http://sa-vn.com:2020/api/users/user', [
    'form_params' => $body
]);
```

**to**

```
$response = $client->get('http://sa-vn.com:2020/api/users/user', [
    'json' => $body
]);
```